# MySQL replace all whitespaces with -

Tags: mysql, sql

how could i remove ALL whitespaces from a row?
I see here alot of same question but all answers ar to use replace option. Replace will work only to strip one spaces, not all.

ex: a  b      c to become a-b-c

Thanks.

Comment: Replace should work to strip all spaces.

Comment: Huh, you have right. But i know that i`ve tryed and doesn`t work. Thanks.

Comment: @oriceon Well, we need to see your code, then. And consider the possibility that the things you're trying to strip aren't actually spaces, too.

Comment: If your goal is to generate friendly URLs (also called... oh, I don't remember their nickname at the moment) you should take a more reliable approach than just replacing spaces with dashes.

Comment: @Alessandro The url-friendly version of a piece of text is a "slug".

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This can be achieved with the following MySQL Function:

```
SELECT REPLACE( table.field, ' ', '-' ) FROM table;
```

This should replace all the whitespace to a -

Comment: You'll want `FROM table` in that example, not `FROM field`.

Comment: Note that this won't change your database values that are stored, it will only convert the spaces to dashes for this specific query's result set.

Comment: To replace them in the database, use @faiz's answer below:

Answer (score 6):

```
update image set path =  REPLACE( image.path, ' ', '-' ) where path like '% %'
```

if you would like to update the path in mysql itself use the update for all rows which have spaces withe %20

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
replace('a b c',' ','-')
```

Comment: Standard SQL uses single quotes as string delimiter.

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE table SET table.field = REPLACE( table.field, ' ', '-' );
```

This will update all the fields, replacing all spaces with hyphens. This will actually modify the data in the tables. Fokko's answer above will change only the data that is pulled, therefore not changing the actual data.