# How read space between the letter when searching a item

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How to read space between the letter when searching for an item. suppose my product name is Pepsi. sometimes they enter p e ps i like this my query as follows.

```
 if(isset($input['dsr_commonsearch']) && $input['dsr_commonsearch']){
        $query->where('dsr.company', 'LIKE', $input['dsr_commonsearch'])->orWhere('dsr.contact_name','LIKE', $input['dsr_commonsearch']); 
    }
```

Comment: Replace all whitespace in the column and then do search on that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103116/mysql-replace-all-whitespaces-with/47091140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I will assume by read you mean how to get rid of the spaces.
Use the following functions to get rid of the spaces.

For just spaces, use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

`$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);`

This will get rid of all the spaces in your given string.

For all whitespace (including tabs and line ends), use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

`$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);`

This will get rid of all the whitespace in your given string.

If you literally want to read the spaces, there is a function called [substr_count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) to get the number of occurrences:

`$space_count = substr_count($string," ");`

This will count all the spaces in your given string.

Comment: how I can integrate into my code Rian Zaman

Comment: Try the following, it's not tested tho, if any error let me know.
$query->where('dsr.company', 'LIKE', '%' . preg_replace("/\s+/", '',$input['dsr_commonsearch']) . '%')->orWhere('dsr.contact_name','LIKE', '%' . preg_replace("/\s+/", '',$input['dsr_commonsearch']) . '%');

Comment: Glad to hear it, have fun coding :) @Alex